# SHA-1 in C on little-endian environment

Tags: c, endianness, sha

Most implementations of SHA-1 (even on Wikipedia) I came across are coded for big-endian runtimes. So I'm trying to implement my own version for my machine (little-endian).

I've followed the pseudo-code form Wikipedia and have the following code. I found a function that converts the byte ordering but still not getting the correct output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define rotateleft(x,n) ((x<<n) | (x>>(32-n)))

unsigned int endian_reverse(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int m = 0;
    m |= n << 24;
    m |= ((n >> 8) << 24) >> 8;
    m |= ((n << 8) >> 24) << 8;
    m |= n >> 24;
    return m;
}

void SHA1(unsigned char * str1)
{
    unsigned long int h0,h1,h2,h3,h4,a,b,c,d,e,f,k,temp;

    h0 = 0x67452301;
    h1 = 0xEFCDAB89;
    h2 = 0x98BADCFE;
    h3 = 0x10325476;
    h4 = 0xC3D2E1F0;

    unsigned char * str;

    str = (unsigned char *)malloc(strlen((const char *)str1)+100);
    strcpy((char *)str,(const char *)str1);

    int current_length = strlen((const char *)str);
    int original_length = current_length;

    str[current_length] = 0x80;
    str[current_length + 1] = '\0';

    char ic = str[current_length];

    current_length++;
    int ib = current_length % 64;

    int i, j;

    if(ib<56)
        ib = 56-ib;
    else
        ib = 120 - ib;

    for(i=0;i < ib;i++)
    {
        str[current_length]=0x00;
        current_length++;
    }

    str[current_length + 1]='\0';

    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        str[current_length]=0x0;
        current_length++;
    }

    str[current_length] = (original_length * 8) / 0x100 ;
    current_length++;
    str[current_length] = (original_length * 8) % 0x100;
    current_length++;
    str[current_length+i]='\0';

    int number_of_chunks = current_length/64;
    unsigned long int word[80];

    for(i=0;i<number_of_chunks;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<16;j++)
        {
            word[j] = 
                str[i*64 + j*4 + 0] * 0x1000000 + str[i*64 + j*4 + 1] * 0x10000 + 
                str[i*64 + j*4 + 2] * 0x100 + str[i*64 + j*4 + 3];
        }
        for(j=16;j<80;j++)
        {
            word[j] = rotateleft((word[j-3] ^ word[j-8] ^ word[j-14] ^ word[j-16]),1);
        }
        a = h0;
        b = h1;
        c = h2;
        d = h3;
        e = h4;
        for(int m=0;m<80;m++)
        {
            if(m<=19)
            {
                f = (b & c) | ((~b) & d);
                k = 0x5A827999;
            }
            else if(m<=39)
            {
                f = b ^ c ^ d;
                k = 0x6ED9EBA1;
            }
            else if(m<=59)
            {
                f = (b & c) | (b & d) | (c & d);
                k = 0x8F1BBCDC;
            }
            else
            {
                f = b ^ c ^ d;
                k = 0xCA62C1D6;
            }
            temp = (rotateleft(a,5) + f + e + k + word[m]) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
            e = d;
            d = c;
            c = rotateleft(b,30);
            b = a;
            a = temp;

        }

        h0 = h0 + a;
        h1 = h1 + b;
        h2 = h2 + c;
        h3 = h3 + d;
        h4 = h4 + e;

    }

    h0 = endian_reverse(h0);
    h1 = endian_reverse(h1);
    h2 = endian_reverse(h2);
    h3 = endian_reverse(h3);
    h4 = endian_reverse(h4);

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Hash: %x %x %x %x %x",h0, h1, h2, h3, h4);
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main()
{
    SHA1((unsigned char *)"abc");
    return 0;
}
```

SHA-1 ("abc"):

Resulting

```
Hash: f7370736 e388302f 15815610 1ccacd49 e7649bb6
```

Correct (actual)

```
Hash: a9993e36 4706816a ba3e2571 7850c26c 9cd0d89d
```

**Am I doing my endianness conversion correctly or in the correct spot?**

Comment: My output is incorrect. To me, it seems everything is correct, but clearly there is a mistake somewhere.

Comment: I've clarified the question at the end. But I guess to narrow it down: "Am I doing my endianness conversion correctly?"

Comment: Okay, I hope to have cleared it up the main body now.

Comment: Most implementations I have seen are for both big-endian and little endian. Try this link, it's for little endian https://github.com/B-Con/crypto-algorithms/blob/master

Comment: The byte-reverse function works ([proof](http://haroldbot.nl/?q=let+m+%3D+0%2C+m+%3D+m+%7C+n+%3C%3C+24%2C+m+%3D+m+%7C+%28%28n+%3E%3E+8%29+%3C%3C+24%29+%3E%3E+8%2C+m+%3D+m+%7C+%28%28n+%3C%3C+8%29+%3E%3E+24%29+%3C%3C+8%2C+m+%3D+m+%7C+n+%3E%3E+24+in+m+%3D%3D+%28n+%3C%3C+24%29+%7C+%28n+%3E%3E+24%29+%7C+%28%28n+%26+0xFF00%29+%3C%3C+8%29+%7C+%28%28n+%26+0xFF0000%29+%3E%3E+8%29)), it's an usual implementation though

Comment: Note: In general, `malloc(strlen((const char *)str1)+100)` --> too small an allocation. I'd expect rounded-up multiples 64.

Comment: By the way endianness comes into play when *reinterpreting memory*, not for just general arithmetic (including bitwise operations). There is no reinterpretation in this code so it should not matter.

Comment: Notice the constants, they're converted to big-endian. As defined in the SHA-1 standard.

Comment: That's just how numbers are written. The constant `0x67452301` may appear in memory as the bytes `01 23 45 67` but that only affects the meaning of the code if those bytes are accessed individually, which does not happen here.

Comment: You almost never need to care about endianness. The one case where endianness can possibly matter is interpreting arithmetic data types (e.g. `unsigned int`) as arrays of characters. This may happen when doing file IO or fiddling bits in a non-portable manner. Your program doesn't, so any reference to endianness in it is an error. See [The byte order fallacy](https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html?m=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I doing my endianness conversion correctly or in the correct spot?

Endianness conversion `endian_reverse(()` is incorrect when `unsigned` is not 32-bit.

Endianness conversion not used in correct spot.  Endian conversion not needed.

Other issues exists.

---

Code is *assuming* `unsigned long int` is 32-bit.  When `unsigned long int` is 64-bit, I can get the same answer as OP.

Save yourself time: There is no reason to use loose types here.  Use `uint32_t, uint8_t`.  For array sizing and string lengths use `size_t`.  Avoid signed types and constants.

---

By changing `unsigned long` --> `uint32_t` and dropping `h0 = endian_reverse(h0); ... h7 = endian_reverse(h7);` I came up with

```
Hash: a9993e36 4706816a ba3e2571 7850c26c 9cd0d89d
```

---

Other suggestions.

**Multiple of 64**

`size` in `str = malloc(size)` should be a multiple of 64

**Stay within multiples of 64**

`str[current_length+i]='\0';` can write outside allocation.

**Alternate size storing**

Works for *all* `size_t` values up to 2<sup>64-3</sup> - 1.

```
  size_t current_length = ...

  // append length in bits
  uint64_t current_length_bits = current_length;
  current_length_bits *= 8;
  for (i = 8; i > 0; ) {
    i--;
    str[current_length + i] = (unsigned char) current_length_bits;
    current_length_bits >>= 8;
  }
  current_length += 8;
```

Comment: Are you compiling on a big-endian machine?

Comment: @xornoz As I see it - machine endian makes no difference in this code.  It is the wrong size of the various types that is messing the code.  What lines of code do you think make a difference because of machine endian?

Comment: @xornoz How do you see endian of `h0` as important here?  The constant needs to have the value of `0x67452301` regardless of machine endian.

Comment: Thats already converted to big-endian. The standards constants are as follows: `H0 = 67452301  
H1 = EFCDAB89  
H2 = 98BADCFE  
H3 = 10325476  
H4 = C3D2E1F0.`   See here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3174#page-6 (§6.1.1)

Comment: @xornoz Endian-ness is how data is stored in memory.  `h0 = 0x67452301` does not specified how data is stored in memory.  Save time, set aside endian concerns.  Look at `str[...] * 0x1000000` which is _signed_ integer multiplication instead of _unsigned_.  Re-code with fixed width types and unsigned math.  "Most implementations of SHA-1 (even on wikipedia) I came across are coded for big-endian runtimes." is a false premise.

Comment: Hooray! fixed by changing the datatypes of i, j, and word to `uint32_t`. Thanks for the explanation, I most defiantly need to brush up my endianness understanding

Comment: @xornoz SHA algorithms universally use _unsigned math_.  It is not _endian_ getting in your way as much as signed math.  Drop the `int`, embrace the `uintN_t`.

Comment: You may want to store `h0, h1, h2, ...` in to a `uint8_t` buffer. That's when endian-ness matters. This code is using `printf` to print the values `h0, h1, h2...` so endian-ness doesn't matter.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani "In a practical application, the hash result is often stored in a single uint8_t array" I'd disagree about that design approach instead have used a `union` of `uint32_t` and `uint8_t` arrays - which insures `uint32_t` alignment. In that case the access via the member `uint8_t` may benefit with prior/post endian adjustments. Yet overall I'd say we agree on more than not.

Comment: Actually I was wrong. You can write `h0, h1...` in to buffer by using `>>` operator. This doesn't require endian check. Some implementations use `memcpy, fwrite` etc. to write the memory in `&h0` in to a buffer, this needs flipping the byte order for little-endian. The latter method is pointlessly complicated and is also used in many places.